# How can I run this simple node.js code synchronously using async.js?

Tags: node.js, async.js

This is a simple function which will get a post url and return the post id of that url.

```
function findPostIdByUrl (url) {

  var id;

  Post.findOne({url}, '_id', function (err, post) {
    if (err) throw err;
    id = post.id;
  });

  return id;
}
```

but it doesn't return the actual id, because it run asynchronously. I want to first run Post.fin...  code which will assign the post id to the id variable, and then run return id.

I've tried my best but I didn't figure out how can I do that. Is there any way to accomplish that?(whether by using async.js or not)

Comment: I'm guessing promises/async-await can't be used?

Comment: I don't know how, I've search on the internet but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do here is get all the data from your request using async/await

so your code here will look like:

```
async function findPostIdByUrl (url) {
   var id;
   var post = await Post.findOne({url}, '_id')
   id = post.id
   return id;
}
```

Comment: It is not the valid code, when I run it I get: SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

Comment: can you post your function please?

Comment: and your node has to be v7.6 minimum or you cant use async/await (i m pretty sure its 7.6 but i m not 100% sure)

Comment: async function findPostIdByUrl (url) {
   var id;
   var post = await Post.findOne({url}, '_id')
   id = post.id
   return id;
}

var id = findPostIdByUrl('i-am-gonna-create-a-post');
console.log(id);

Comment: Oh I am using node 6.

Comment: So i suggest that you upgrade your node version its v8 already :) and your code miss something. You are calling your function and then console.log, but your function will take time to execute so your console.log will be called before your function returned anything. I will post an answer soon

Comment: I wish I could. the problem is I am building a big web application using node 6(more than 12000 lines of code), and I fear from my app to be broke by updating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
function findPostIdByUrl (url) {
  var id;
  return Post.findOne({url}, '_id').then((post) => {
      id = post.id
      return id;
  })
  .catch((err) => {/* Do something with err */})
}
```

You can actually skip setting the id.

```
return Post.findOne({url}, '_id').then((post) => {
   return post.id;
})
```

Also Post this, `findPostIdByUrl` should be used as

```
findPostIdByUrl(url).then((id) => {/* Whatever you need to do with id*/})
```

Comment: It works but I want another thing. I want to be able to use the function like this: var id = findPostIdByUrl(url);

Comment: Unfortunately, Thats not how async works in JS.
You can very well use the async solution below by @kikiwie. That would to an extent make it look like `var id = await  findPostIdByUrl(url);`
But be advised. thats just a syntactic sugar